# Postgres create temp table for each request from web application and that temp table will be accessible across all functions inside Postgresql.?

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I want to create a temp table for each request from a web application. The temp table should be accessible to all the functions present inside the Postgres db.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you. I created the temp table inside one function . Then I called another function from this function but I am unable to access the temp table which I have created in another function. I want to create a global temp table. Is any other way to create thread safe data inside a database

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Begin,

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE <table_name>
(.....);
```

And while returning I tried returning the whole table data

```
RETURN QUERY select * from <table_name>;
```

By this way, it started working